# How to generate all possible rankings of a document set when each document can take one of 2 types?

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

I need to generate possible ranking of all possible ranking of `n` documents. I understand that the permutations of an array `{1, 2,..., n}` will give me the set of all possible rankings. 
My problem is a bit more complex as each document could take one of 2 possible types. Therefore, in all there are n!*2<sup>n</sup> possible rankings.

For instance, let us say I have 3 documents a, b, and c. Then possible rankings are the following:

```
a1 b1 c1
a1 b1 c2
a1 b2 c1
a1 b2 c2
a2 b1 c1
a2 b1 c2
a2 b2 c1
a2 b2 c2
a1 c1 b1
a1 c1 b2
a1 c2 b1
a1 c2 b2
a2 c1 b1
a2 c1 b2
a2 c2 b1
a2 c2 b2
b1 a1 c1
b1 a1 c2
b1 a2 c1
b1 a2 c2
b2 a1 c1
b2 a1 c2
...
```

What would be an elegant way to generate such rankings?

Comment: Using this could be elegant http://maths.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/maths/combinatorics/CombinationGenerator.html

Comment: Thanks, but I think my problem is different from "generating all combinations of a given size from the specified set of elements". Specifically, once `a1` is picked `a2` cannot be picked in that ranking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kind of cross product between the permutations of B={a,b, ...} and the k-combinations of T{1,2} where k is the the number of elements in B. Say we take a p from Perm(B), e.g. p=(b,c,a) and a c from 3-Comb(T), e.g. c=(2,1,1) then we would merge p and c into (b2,c1,a1).
I don't really know if it's elegant but I would choose an algorithm to generate sequentially the permutations of B (cf [TAOCP Volume 4 fascicle 2b](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html)) and for each permutation apply the above "product" with all the k-combinations generated sequentially (or stored in an array if k is small) ([cf TAOCP Volume 4 fascicle 3a](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html)).

```
B={a,b,c, ... }
T={1,2}
k=length(B)

reset_perm(B)
do
  p = next_perm(B)
  reset_comb(T,k)
  do
    c = next_kcomb(T,k)
    output product(p,c)
  while not last_kcomb(T,k)
while not last_perm(B)
```